# How to copy a file from one container (Docker) running in one server to another container running on a different server?

Tags: docker, server, containers, ip-address

I have a file in a Docker container running on server A. I need to get this file to a docker container running on server B (different IP address)

Using "docker cp" can I copy files from host to container and vice-versa. With 'scp' I can copy files between servers, but how can I copy a file from one container running in server A to a container running in server B?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in multiple steps

1. Copy file from container to host on Server A (using docker cp)
2. Copy file from Server A to server B (using SCP)
3. Copy file from host to container on server B (using docker cp)

If you wrap the steps in a script that takes the IP's of servers as well as the container names and you can abstract away the different steps. This script can then be run form either of the servers (or from a third one), basically from anywhere where you can execute commands through ssh on the servers

Comment: The problem is, the action of copying a file from file-container-serverA to container-serverB is comming from container in server B.

Comment: Okay I see. What is the use case? Would it make sense with a shared storage area for example?